# Music player seekBar doesn't begin from 0

Tags: music-player, xiaomi, miui

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 pro with MIUI 8 7.5.11. In the default music player when I try to drag the seekbar to the beginning it automatically releases at 00:04-05, not at 00:00. Is it a bug?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please try to upload images directly (imgur)  and try not to provide an external link, this time I have edited for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try Using Any other MusicPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

your system has a bug, try to go on impostation(on the new dedicated section of the new miui version for system apps) and cancel all data of the application. If don't work go on PlaySotre and download another playmusic